# Warning: Attempt to present on whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I know that there are a million questions like this but solutions didn't work for me.

Everyone is saying, that you need to push to the next view controller inside the ViewDidAppear which is what I do, but still does not work.

I am using PARSE, and as per the instructions when the user is logged in - I want to skip the login screen and open the next one.

here is my code inside LoginViewController.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Check if user is cached and linked to Facebook, if so, bypass login
    if ([PFUser currentUser] && [PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) {
        NSLog(@"Settings Screen should open automatically");
        [self _presentUserSettingsSetupViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)_presentUserSettingsSetupViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main_iPhone";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UserSettingsSetupViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserSettingsSetup"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:animated completion:nil];
}
```

I see the log message, but the other view controller does not open - I still stay in the login view controller.

Comment: You say that you are presenting the view controller in `viewDidAppear:` but the code you have posted is presenting the view controller in `viewWillAppear:`. There is a difference between `WILL` where the view controller has not yet been presented and `DID` where the view controller has been presented.

Comment: oh I didn't even paid attention to this... My eye was focused on the Appear word... Sorry for it - make it an answer so as to accept it.

Comment: Will transfer to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are presenting the view controller in `viewDidAppear:` but the code you have posted is presenting the view controller in `viewWillAppear:`.

There is a difference between WILL where the view controller has not yet been presented and DID where the view controller has been presented.